# How to add proper platfom (hits.datasource) to the tabel in the BigQuery?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery with exported data from Google analytics. Trying to add the platform to the session-level report (don't know how to call this dimension properly but basically, I need split 'app' and 'web', so 'device type' is not sufficiently enough).

I'm trying to use `hits.datasource` but there's one problem. It is not really session level dimension. I mean it is, but because of specificity of the tracking in my company, sometimes there's a couple of different data sources for one session.

So here's the overall script I'm currently working on:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  'DE' as Country,
  FORMAT_DATE("%d.%m.%Y", PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d",date)) AS Date,
  channelGrouping AS Channel,
  trafficSource.medium as Medium,    
  trafficSource.source as Source,    
  trafficSource.campaign as Campaign,    
  hits[OFFSET(0)].datasource AS Platform, -- part I'm struggling with -- 
  device.deviceCategory as Device,
  CASE WHEN device.operatingSystem ='iOS' OR device.operatingSystem ='Android' then device.operatingSystem else 'Other' END as OS,
  CASE WHEN SUM(totals.visits)>0 THEN SUM(totals.visits) ELSE 0 END AS Sessions,
  CASE WHEN SUM(totals.totalTransactionRevenue)>0 THEN SUM(totals.totalTransactionRevenue)/POW(10,6) ELSE 0 END AS Revenue,
  CASE WHEN SUM(totals.transactions)>0 THEN SUM(totals.transactions) ELSE 0 END AS Orders,
  CASE WHEN SUM(totals.pageviews) >0 then SUM(totals.pageviews) ELSE 0 END as Pageviews,
  CASE WHEN SUM(totals.screenviews) >0 then SUM(totals.screenviews) ELSE 0 END as Screenviews,
  CASE WHEN SUM(totals.bounces) >0 then SUM(totals.bounces) ELSE 0 END as Bounces 
FROM
  `oval-unity-88908.97525772.ga_sessions_*` t
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

I've left `hits[OFFSET(0)].datasource` as a temporary substitute but I would like to put there the most used data source in the session.

Here's a couple of my attempts to substitute that line of code. Nothing worked yet.

```
(SELECT ht.datasource FROM (SELECT datasource, SUM(t.totals.hits) FROM t.hits GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1) ht) AS Platfrom,
```

.

```
(SELECT ht.datasource FROM (SELECT datasource, COUNT(1) FROM t.hits GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1) ht) AS Platfrom,
```

.

```
(SELECT hits.datasource FROM UNNEST(t.hits) ORDER BY hits.hitNumber LIMIT 1) AS Platform,
```

Looking forward to your advices on how to improve that script or maybe even another approach to the thing I'm trying to do. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You somehow need to decide how to aggregate this information. I'm usually using the most frequent datasource:

```sql
SELECT
  (SELECT datasource FROM t.hits GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC limit 1) mostFrequDatasource
  ,(SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT datasource) FROM t.hits) allDataSources
  ,SUM(totals.visits) sessions
FROM
  `ga_sessions` t
GROUP BY 1,2
```

For testing I added 'allDataSources' showing all datasources appearing in a session.

Answer (score 0):

Your last attempt was correctly using UNNEST but you also need to do JOIN with the table:

```
FROM UNNEST(t.hits) JOIN t
```